# When can HAC standard errors be appiled

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, hac

In my one-way and two-way fixed effects models, I detected autocorrelation and heteroscedasticity.
Therefore, I want to use HAC standard errors to correct my standard errors. Are there some preconditions, for example regarding N, n, or T, to my models that HAC standard errors can be applied?

Comment: The theory of HAC errors is asymptotic, so in principle it works better if you have a large sample. Otherwise there's no guarantee that the errors will have good statistical properties.

Comment: @CarlosSáez in my model N=40, n =367, and T= 17 do you think that is enough to apply HAC standard errors?

Comment: I think it should be enough. But I'm don't have a lot of experience with fixed effect models, so maybe is better if someone else confirms it.